# Using groupby in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel eloquent and doing a group by.

My query as below

```
$pickups= Pickup::select('pickups.*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                                        ->groupBy('address_id')
                                        ->havingRaw('total > 0')
                                        ->get();
```

How do I add a function in the model to return all the rows in that group?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how you could turn the query above into a function that returns the query results? Btw, you can't select * columns in a GROUP BY query.

Comment: yup. And the query results is a group of results group by address id. Just wondering if its possible in laravel. Now i have to foreach of the pickups and fetch the pickup rows

Comment: What kind of output format do you expect out of the query? Eloquent will returns the object in which you'll have to do foreach to access each row and calls like pickups->total to access the value, which is what you're currently doing I suppose.